# Convert into a system of two first order ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The following must be solved:
$$u'' +\frac{2}{t}u' + u^{n} = 0  $$
with
$$u(0) = 1,\,u'(0) = 0 $$
I did make an attempt of sorts though:

Set the one independent variable as follows:
$$u_{0} = t $$ 
Dependent Variables:
$$u_{1} = u$$
$$u_{2} = u'$$
$$u_{3} = u''$$
Then you get:
$$u_{3} = u_{2}'$$
$$u_{2} = u_{1}'$$
$$u_{3} + \frac{2}{u_{0}}u_{2} + (u_{1})^{n}$$
Does this look right? Now I just need to figure out how to solve it via python....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need $u_{3}$.  Your 1st-order system is
$$
u_{1}' = u_{2}, \quad u_{2}' = -(2/t) u_{2} - (u_{1})^{n},
$$
with the initial conditions
$$
u_{1}(0) = 1, \quad u_{2}(0) = 0.
$$
BTW, the only independent variable is time $t$, even in the resulting 1st-order system.